# How to port RPC XDR from UNIX to Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I'm trying to port an open source software (written in C++) from UNIX to Windows, which needs XDR library. I know RPC is UNIX specific but I wanted to know: is there any Windows version of it which could be compiled by using Visual Studio? By the way, I prefer to use Visual Studio and do not switch to Cygwin or MiniGW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution by porting libtirpc-devel from Cygwin repo.